# PIC: Watchdog timer off by a factor of 4

Tags: pic, timer, watchdog

I have a PIC16 (datasheet [here](http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/41419A.pdf)) for which I use the watchdog timer. I configure the watchdog timer as follows:

```
WDTCONbits.WDTPS = 0b01110;
```

According to page 105 of the datasheet, this should configure the watchdog timer for 16 seconds. However, the timer interrupt is called after only 4 seconds. (I have tested the timer with other values and the 4x discrepancy always persists.)

My first thought was that it was due to the 4xPLL being enabled. But as far as I understand, the watchdog timer is based upon the `LFINTOSC` clock, which is invariant under the 4xPLL.

Why is my watchdog timer running at four times the speed it should be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the datasheet you provided, at page 105, the value you should program is: 01110. Thus the whole register should be 0b00011101 -> 0x1D.

It seems that you already did so. But are you sure that the definition of WDTCONbits.WDTPS doesn't contain a bug ? Try to assign to the whole register directly.

The watchdog is powered by the internal low frequency oscillator. It has nothing to do with the PLL.

Answer (score 0):

The timing bits are bits 5 to 1, which means for 16 seconds the register should be written with `0b00011100` (or the LSB can be 1 if you are controlling the WDT in software).
Not sure why it would be 4 times off rather than 2, but try writing the above value directly to the full register (i.e. `WDTCON`) and see if it works correctly.

Also, check the errata for the part, to see if any bugs are mentioned regarding the WDT.